# How can I make "log in" change to "log out" on my menu bar (USING CODE ONLY)?

Tags: php, wordpress, hyperlink, menu, navigation

I am working out of WordPress, I have inserted a custom menu in the header.php file in my theme.

I now dont have access to my menu through WordPress appearance >menus on my dashboard..

Normally , a plug in can make certain menu links visible to select role or users.

But i have no access there .

How can I control the menu to show to certain users or by a specific role (using CODE ONLY)?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding "Log In" and "Log Out" to the menu, you add a filter to your functions.php which checks if the user is logged in or not, then displays the appropriate link:

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'xyz_add_members_to_menus', 10, 2 );
function xyz_add_members_to_menus( $items, $args ) {
    if( 'primary' === $args->theme_location ) {
        if (is_user_logged_in()) {
            $items .= '<li><a href="/logout/" title="Log Out">Log Out</a></li>';
        } else {
            $items .= '<li><a href="/login/" title="Log In">Log In</a></li>';
        }
    }
    return $items;
}
```

Comment: Will this work any if I cannot control the custom coded menu from the appearance ) menus dashboard?

Comment: The code above is a filter, which adds to the menu created in Appearance / Menus. It takes the code used to build existing menu, then appends either the Log In or Log Out link to end of it.